# Membership to WordPress website (artlist)

Tags: wordpress

So I am doing a small project with my friends, and we are making like artlist.io website (ish) it needs to accept payments from users, paying members to have an unlimited download of our audio files, but non paying members should be able to listen to the beats/sound effects, just not have access to the download.

does anyone know how you would do this, and what plugin you recommend (does not need to be free)

I have looked over MemberPress and few others but no one from the support is willing to answer, and I don't want to pay for something that might not work.

hopeful to get some answers!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] (and earn a badge while you are at it) / Also read our [ask] page and [edit] your question to improve it.
Good questions tend to receive quicker, better answers from the community.

Comment: What did you ask their support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, any membership plugin will be able to meet the requirements that you have. I've recently done some similar projects using MemberPress, and it's good. PPM is also a good choice. You might require some coding for doing exactly what you want. Otherwise, any membership plugin will do.